# customer session is empty in custom module magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have made a custom module which uses customer session, but its strange, on live site its not returning customer data.
i have tried following methods:

```
$sessCustomer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    echo '<pre>';print_r($sessCustomer->getCustomer()->getData()); echo '</pre>';exit;
```

it returns:

```
Array
(
    [website_id] => 1
)
```

if i print the customer session:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getData();
```

this returns (exact output):

```
     array(
[_session_validator_data] => Array
        (
            [remote_addr] => 58.65.183.10
            [http_via] => 
            [http_x_forwarded_for] => 58.65.183.10
            [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
        )

    [session_hosts] => Array
            (
                [bestevalue.info] => 1
            )
    [messages] => Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection Object
            (
                [_messages:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_lastAddedMessage:protected] => 
            )
    [id] => 
)
```

i am exhausted here , i am logged in, can see the customer dashboard with customer info on it but not been able to use that session in my custom module, please guide me how to fix this.

**Update:**

i have checked in /app/etc/local.xml that session type is file

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
```

so is there different method of extracting session info with php ? what am i doing wrong?

**Update 2:**

i have used router as well to make pretty url 
`public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)`

on start of this action i placed

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));`

but still not working with router without one it is working for example directly accessing the action :

`site.com/module/controller/action`

it works but not with router. any thoughts?
thanks,

Comment: Same thing if you print Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getData() ?

Comment: yes doing this outputs: Array
(
    [website_id] => 1
)

Comment: Well the session is definitely not filled yet. Where are you calling the session (so where is this code located)? Are you 100% sure you are logged in ?

Comment: yes i am definitely logged in, i can view the customer dashboard, the code is located in my custom module (controller) where i have to check the customer login status ( Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ) to access in order to allow to view the resulting layout. event this result in false so it redirects back to customer/account

Comment: do you have custom controller / action for cutom module ?

Comment: this might be issue as magento start frontend session in predispatch action of controller.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple:

```
private function _getCustomerSession() {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
}
```

This initializes the session and returns it. Call this function like this:

```
$this->_getCustomerSession()->getCustomer()
```

And it will have the data available.

**Update for googlers and future reference**: I had this issue again today and my own solution didn't work (like the question). Further investigation revealed I have overridden the `preDispatch()` function in my custom module to check if the module was enabled in backend and if not redirect to homepage with error. In this case the solution was to -obviously- call `parent::preDispatch();`

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have put this in my controller class and called the method as you said, but again this only results in `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer Object` with `[_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => 1
        )`

Comment: Strange, I had the same thing in my test (only website_id) and this helped... But now I can't seem to reproduce this. Are you calling it in a pre dispatch function or just in the controller function?

Comment: yes its an unexpected situation for me here (grinding my teeth) i am calling in only in my controller function.

Comment: Maybe you can check the $_SESSION object directly to make sure it's in there ? That will indicate if it's a session-related problem or just a matter of the customer session not being initialized at that moment.

Comment: i just did that ok its strange that within customer/accountcontroller the session object at least shows `[id] => 18` but in my custom module if i print `$_SESSION` it shows `[id] =>` its blank in my module the id index.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that most likely the controller you are extending for your custom module action is not the correct class. 
I've also just had the same problem and after an hour or so of bashing my head on the screen I realized my controller was extended this

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
```

and not this

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
```

I'm not sure without going into these what the main difference is but I know you wont have a customer session extending the first class!

Answer (score 0):

I suffered by not getting the customer session inside my custom module. It was working in my localhost fine but in server i couldn't able to get the customer session.

I have found the solution by replacing the frontname in config.xml,

i have just changed `<frontName>votingsytem</frontName> to <frontName>vote</frontName>`

i got the customer session it work fine in live server.

I hope this will be useful.

**Before:**

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
     <votingsytem>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
           <module>Vgs_Votingsytem</module>
           <frontName>votingsytem</frontName>
        </args>
     </votingsytem>        
  </routers>
  <layout>
     <updates>
        <votingsytem>
           <file>votingsytem.xml</file>
        </votingsytem>
     </updates>
  </layout>
```

**After:**

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
     <votingsytem>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
           <module>Vgs_Votingsytem</module>
           <frontName>vote</frontName>
        </args>
     </votingsytem>        
  </routers>
  <layout>
     <updates>
        <votingsytem>
           <file>votingsytem.xml</file>
        </votingsytem>
     </updates>
  </layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I've spent more than 3 hours googling the reason, and at the end I randomly decided to remove the Controller constructor overriding and Yes!, the session came back!.

Yet, I was overriding it correctly by calling the parent constructor!.