# Magento. Customer online, but not logged in

Tags: magento, authentication

Here is the problem: 
I am using a script to create a user in Magento and trying to login this user if he he/she already exists.

```
try {
        // If new, save customer information
$customer -> firstname = $firstname;
    $customer -> lastname = $lastname;
    $customer -> email = $email;
    $customer -> password_hash = md5($password);
    if ($customer -> save()) {
        echo $customer -> firstname . " " . $customer -> lastname . " information is saved!";
        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->save();
    } else {
        echo "An error occured while saving customer";
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // If customer already exists, initiate login
    if (preg_match('/This customer email already exists/', $e)) {
        $customer -> loadByEmail($email);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $session -> login($email, $password);
        echo $session -> isLoggedIn() ? $session -> getCustomer() -> getName() . ' is online!' : 'not logged in';
    }
}
```

the script echoes "user is online!", but when I go to the main page, it shows me the login button, as if I am not logged in. How do I login the user?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the website id?

You could also check if the customer exist by loadByEmail

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');

$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());

$customer->loadByEmail($email);

// This customer email exists
if($customer->getId()){
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
}
else{
    .....
    $customer->save();
}
```

or

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);

if(!$customer->getId()){
    $customer->setFirstname($firstname);
    $customer->setLastname($lastname);
    .....
    $customer->save();
}

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

See

- [Auto Login customer to Magento](http://www.magentozend.com/blog/2011/11/21/auto-login-customer-to-magento/)
- [Programatically create customer](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-create-customer-and-order-in-magento-with-full-blown-one-page-checkout-process-under-the-hood/)

Comment: nope, it didn't do the trick. The customer just seems to be logged in, but he/she is not authentificated, the seesion doesn't start

Comment: Did you add `Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));`? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478013/customer-session-is-empty-in-custom-module-magento